Can I recover Bitcoin after security codes lost
My colleague says he still has 50-100 bitcoins on an old hard drive, but he can no longer access them because he does not have the security codes. It is an bitcoin-qt wallet I think. I have read some things about how I can remove the blockchain with the bitcoin core app. But does this also mean that I can get these bitcoins back in a way? Does anyone know what to do? A nice compensation awaits the real helping hand.

If a wallet is protected with a passphrase, it is not possible for someone to spend money in that wallet without knowing the passphrase.
This is arguably the most vital function of a wallet and any established wallet will implement this protection well.
Deleting local blockchain data accumulated by a wallet application has no effect on this aspect of wallet security.
Offering compensation likely leads to a deluge of tempting offers from thieves pretending to be recovery agents. I think it safest to assume they are all fake.

I depends on how secure of a password your colleague picked to secure their wallet. If it's not a very strong one, it may be possible to brute force. In a any case, make a backup of the wallet in case future developments in cryptography may allow the password to be cracked. And be wary of scammers offering wallet recovery services.
